# Save XML data to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have this xml file, and I want to save value `NUMBER` (for example) to a SQL Server table.

```
<ORDER>
  <ORDER_HEADER>
    <NUMBER>10945</NUMBER>
    <TIME>7.8.2013 12:45:20</TIME>
    <NOTE>this is Note</NOTE>   
  </ORDER_HEADER>
</ORDER>
```

This is my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\L\\Desktop\\data.xml");
var NUMBER = doc.Descendants("NUMBER");
var TIME = doc.Descendants("TIME");
var NOTE = doc.Descendants("NOTE");

foreach (var cislo in NUMBER)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***");
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
       cmd.CommandText = "Update CISLO SET cislo = @cislo1;";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cislo1", doc);

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }

 MessageBox.Show("OK");
```

I get this error:

> There is no mapping from object type System.Xml.Linq.XDocument to a known managed provider native type.

On row:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing 'doc', which is your XDocument, into the parameter.  Try changing

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cislo1", doc);
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cislo1", cislo);
```

Comment: probably should be `cislo.Value`

Comment: YES!! cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cislo1", cislo.Value);

Comment: Good call, @MarcinJuraszek